# ¿Como seleccionar solo los primeros registros de un ranking cuando hay varios grupos de ranking desde un procedimiento almacenado en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure

Tengo el siguiente procedimiento almacenado en MySQL, me funciona pero sin embargo me trae registros de mas, me refiero a que existen varios registros que coinciden en casi todos los campos menos en la serie y en la fecha, por ello decidi ordenarlos como en un ranking.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`usuarioroot`@`%` PROCEDURE `spRank`()
BEGIN

set @report_rank := 0;
set @current  := 0; 

select a.*, 
       @report_rank := IF(@current  = clave , @report_rank + 1, 1) AS report_rank,
                                            @current  := clave              
  from (
    SELECT tabla1.serie,Count(*) as cantSerie,fecha,  
        CASE WHEN DateDiff(fecha,Now())<0 Then 0 Else  
        CASE WHEN DateDiff(fecha,Now())>0 AND DateDiff(fecha,Now())<20 Then 1 
                        Else 2 End End As Codfecha, 
                        DateDiff(Max(fecha),Now()) as DiasExp, 
                        CASE WHEN IsNull(seriePdf) Then 'No' Else 'Si' end as EnPdf,  
                        tabla2.clave,campo4 as antiguo 
                        From bd1.tabla1, bd1.tabla2, bd2.tabla3  ,
                            (SELECT tabla2.clave 
                                From bd1.tabla2, bd2.tabla3 
                                Where tabla2.clave = bd2.tabla3.clave 
                                Group By tabla2.clave) 
                                Subclave
                                Where tabla2.clave = bd2.tabla3.clave  
                                AND tabla1.serie=tabla2.serie  
                                and subclave.clave = tabla2.clave
                                GROUP BY tabla2.clave,tabla1.serie 
                                ) a
            ORDER BY antiguo,clave,fecha DESC,cantSerie,serie;

END
```

Puedo obtener el siguiente resultado:

```
  serie    cantSerie         fecha       Codfecha   DiasExp  EnPdf  clave  antiguo report_rank @current :=clave

123AB0123      5     2016-04-26 00:00:00     0       -114      Si   01A1     NO        1                01A1
123AC0123      4     2014-03-26 00:00:00     0       -876      Si   01A1     NO        2                01A1
123BC0123      1     2013-03-30 00:00:00     0       -1237     Si   01A1     NO        3                01A1
123BD0123      5     2013-03-30 00:00:00     0       -1237     Si   01A1     NO        4                01A1
124BF0123      1     2016-06-10 00:00:00     0       -69       Si   01A2     NO        1                01A2
123BD0023      1     2013-03-30 00:00:00     0       -1237     Si   01A2     NO        2                01A2
```

Pero yo solo quiero los registros que tengan en el report_rank = 1, lo intente usando la clausula where asi: `where @report_rank = 1`  pero no me trae ningun registro y tampoco me marca error, ademas tambien me gustaria que en el resultado final no se vean los ultimos 2 campos: `report_rank @current :=clave`

En pocas palabras quiero obtener el siguiente resultado:

```
  serie    cantSerie         fecha       Codfecha   DiasExp  EnPdf  clave  antiguo 

123AB0123      5     2016-04-26 00:00:00     0       -114      Si   01A1     NO        
124BF0123      1     2016-06-10 00:00:00     0       -69       Si   01A2     NO
```

Comment: @MiquelColl También ya lo he intentado y en esa situacion me marca un error de columna desconocida

Comment: Eso es porqué `report_rank` no es una columna de la tabla. se tendría que traducir lógica de `IF(@current  = clave , @report_rank + 1, 1)` a un WHERE o utilizar tablas temporales o agrupaciones.

Comment: @MiquelColl intentare con agrupaciones y tablas temporales aver que tal

Comment: intentaste poner un `HAVING` ? funciona igual que un where, solo que filtra a posteriori

Comment: Gracias @PabloAlcantar Con having funciona perfecto, no lo habia intentado de hecho cuando me mencionaste esa respuesta no crei que habria diferencia, despues me puse a investigar como funciona exactamente having y me di cuenta. La solucion solo fue agregar: `having report_rank = 1`

Comment: la pondré como respuesta, para que la marques como resuelta :)

Comment: @PabloAlcantar claro que si por favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya que intentas filtrar en base a una columna deducida, no es posible filtrar utilizando `WHERE` el cual filtra a priori los resultados en base a las filas. Es por esto que existe la palabra clave `HAVING` la cual filtra a posteriori, es decir, filtra en base a los resultados ya obtenidos.

Tu query quedaría así:

```
select a.*, 
       @report_rank := IF(@current  = clave , @report_rank + 1, 1) AS report_rank,
                                            @current  := clave              
  from (
    SELECT tabla1.serie,Count(*) as cantSerie,fecha,  
        CASE WHEN DateDiff(fecha,Now())<0 Then 0 Else  
        CASE WHEN DateDiff(fecha,Now())>0 AND DateDiff(fecha,Now())<20 Then 1 
                        Else 2 End End As Codfecha, 
                        DateDiff(Max(fecha),Now()) as DiasExp, 
                        CASE WHEN IsNull(seriePdf) Then 'No' Else 'Si' end as EnPdf,  
                        tabla2.clave,campo4 as antiguo 
                        From bd1.tabla1, bd1.tabla2, bd2.tabla3  ,
                            (SELECT tabla2.clave 
                                From bd1.tabla2, bd2.tabla3 
                                Where tabla2.clave = bd2.tabla3.clave 
                                Group By tabla2.clave) 
                                Subclave
                                Where tabla2.clave = bd2.tabla3.clave  
                                AND tabla1.serie=tabla2.serie  
                                and subclave.clave = tabla2.clave
                                GROUP BY tabla2.clave,tabla1.serie 
                                ) a
       HAVING report_rank = 1 -- <== filtra a posteriori
            ORDER BY antiguo,clave,fecha DESC,cantSerie,serie;
```

Otra posible opción hubiese sido calcular este valor dentro del `WHERE`, pero esto hace que sea poco óptimo, ya que estaría calculando esto mismo por cada fila, posiblemente duplicando el tiempo de respuesta.

Comment: Estaba cambiando la forma de ordenamiento solo modifique esto `ORDER BY antiguo,serie,clave,fecha DESC,cantSerie;` y puedes creer que me trae 700 registros mas, no logro comprender porque el ordenamiento puede alterar la cantidad de registros obtenidos, alguna idea?

Comment: @GuillermoVargas tanto si le sacas, como si le pones el having?

Comment: Si cambio la forma de ordenarlos con el having me trae mas o me trae menos registros, pero si quito el having siempre me trae los mismos registros independientemente de la forma en la que este ordenados, osea el ordenamiento me altera la cantidad de registros obtenidos unicamente cuando utilizo el having :/